# Policy gradient theorem proofs

Tags: reinforcement-learning, policy-gradient

I'm looking at two proofs for the policy gradient theorem. [van heeswijk](https://towardsdatascience.com/policy-gradients-in-reinforcement-learning-explained-ecec7df94245) starts of with expressing the policy gradient as a gradient over expected reward trajectories:
[image: easy proof]

and the rest is easy. However [weng](https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2018-04-08-policy-gradient/) starts off with a gradient of the value function of a random state: [image: hard]
and the proof is much more involved, and requires work to express as a function of the stationary distribution of the model states and the Q function.

Are these two approaches equal? is one of them making assumptions the other isn't?

Comment: isn't maximizing the expected return the same as maximizing the expected value function? by the def of value function